# How can I remove a trailing whitespace from a folder name in a remote repository?

Tags: git

I am on a Windows computer, trying checkout the latest commit in a remote repository. In a recent commit, the repository owner added a folder with a name ending with a whitespace. As I am on a Windows computer, this blocks me from using `git checkout main` to checkout the latest commit. When I try to do so, using either `git checkout main` or `git checkout --force main`, it works halfway before returning an error. While it does not switch me to the `main` branch, it modifies some (but not all) of the files that need to be modified to switch me to the `main` branch, which pollutes my working directory.

What I am trying to do is to rename the folder (in this question, `foldername /`) to remove the trailing whitespace (rename it to `foldername/`). The biggest problem blocking me from doing so is that I am unable to checkout any commit that has `foldername /` in it.

After setting `git config core.protectNTFS false`, I have tried `git checkout --force main` to attempt to checkout main, with the intent of then using `git mv "foldername /" "foldername/"` to rename the folder to not include the whitespace. This does not work, since I cannot checkout main due to `foldername /` existing. I have tried to use `git mv "foldername /" "foldername/"` before and after attempting to checkout `main` (with a clean or polluted working directory respectively). Neither of those attempts work, because the folder `"foldername /"` doesn't exist in the working directory. From what I can see, I am stuck in a catch-22: I must have the folder in the working directory before I can rename it, but I need to rename the folder before I can bring it into the working directory.

Is there any way for me to rename the folder without first bringing it into the working directory? Is there way to checkout the commit despite the folder name ending in a whitespace? Am I perhaps missing some other way to break this catch-22?

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions (supposing that `foldername /` is right under the root directory):

1. Dump the root tree object of the commit to a file.
2. Edit the file and remove the trailing whitespace.
3. Create a new tree object from the updated file.
4. Create a new commit from the new root tree object.

Step 1

```
# Dump the root tree object of the commit to a file.
git ls-tree main > temp_tree.txt
```

Step 2

```
# Edit the file and remove the trailing whitespace.
# temp_tree.txt has a line like this, where I use * to represent a space.
# The sha1 value is different in your case.
040000 tree 09a13b897d3d0f528d487c704da540cb952d7606    foldername*

# Remove the trailing space, save and quit.
```

Step 3

```
# Create a new tree object from the updated file.
git mktree < temp_tree.txt

# The command prints a sha1 value which is the new tree object
# Suppose it's f060989b137790b66267c165da36bf829275b88f
```

Step 4

```
# Create a new commit from the new root tree object.
# Here we need to specify a parent for the new commit.
# Two of the candidates would be the parent of the current main head,
# or right the head. It depends on what you plan to do with the new commit,
# replacing the original head or creating a new commit based on the head.
# Suppose you plan to create a new commit base on the head.
# If you know the commit sha1 value of origin/main, use the sha1 value instead
# as origin/main could be updated unexpectedly.
git commit-tree -p origin/main -m "commit message" f060989b137790b66267c165da36bf829275b88f

# git commit-tree creates a new commit and prints its sha1 value.
# Suppose the new commit is 7d94856b1b5b650a085c43f0f5e28b3aa7f70f02
# We can update main to the new commit
git update refs/remotes/origin/main 7d94856b1b5b650a085c43f0f5e28b3aa7f70f02
```

And then you can try `git checkout main` or `git checkout 7d94856b1b5b650a085c43f0f5e28b3aa7f70f02`.

If `foldername /` is deep in the recursive folders, it would be a bit more troublesome. But the solution is the same. Suppose it's at `foo/foldername /`.

In Step 1, we need to get the tree object of `foo`, the parent of `foldername /`, instead of the root tree.

```
git ls-tree origin/main:foo > temp_tree.txt
```

Step 2 and Step 3 are the same. We edit the tree file and remove the trailing space. After that we create a new tree object for `foo`.

Before we finally create a new commit, we need to generate a new root tree, because the sha1 value of `foo` in the root tree has been updated and we need to replace the original sha1 value with the new one.

Similarly, we dump the root tree object to a file.

```
git ls-tree origin/main > temp_tree.txt
# There is a line like this
040000 tree 09a13b897d3d0f528d487c704da540cb952d7606    foo
```

This time, we change the sha1value to the new tree generated in Step 3, save and quit. And then we create the new root tree from the updated temp_tree.txt. After we get the root tree object, we can again create a new commit as we do in previous Step 4.

If it's deeper, we need to create a new tree object for every level of its parent folders upwards until we create the new root tree.

There might be other simpler solutions. This one is what I have tried to solve a similar issue, to amend a corrupted stash entry. In your case, I think it's easier to modify the folder name on a machine that supports the trailing whitespaces.